# Spotify api refresh token return error 400

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, spotify

I try to refresh a Spotify token but the server returns a 400 error.
I use angularjs and typescript

```html
let httpParams = new HttpParams()
  .append("grant_type", "refresh_token")
  .append("refresh_token", token)
  .append("client_id", my_client_id);

  this.http.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", httpParams.toString(), 
  { headers: { 
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },}).subscribe(data => {  
    console.log(data['access_token'])
  })
```

Here is the error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that that the token you are passing as a parameter in   .append("refresh_token", token) is the refresh token initially provided by the API and not the access token? Based on the name of the parameter you might be passing the initial access_token, which would result in the status:400 error.

The initial request via the [Authorization Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) will provide you with both. Make sure to provide the refresh token received at this point when you request your new refresh token and it should work.